# Portlet, Spring, Service Layer injecting HttpSession

Tags: java, spring, portlet

I've got a service layer which is managed by spring. Now at one point I need some informations from the httpsession. Is there a clean way to inject the httpsession directly into my servicelayer?

My portlets are not managed by spring - this point matters in my setup.

Answer (score 0):

Bad idea.

The service layer shouldn't have to know anything about HTTP.

My advice is to pull the information out of the session, bind it to a (validated) object, and make that object a parameter for one of the method calls on your service's interface.

This is NOT the place for injection.

Comment: hmm validated object? need some more infos on that. my problem is, that in my portal env I can't declare a session scope which would been my first choice of storing the needed informations via spring